Generating MySQL Dump via Instance started from AMI
I have a live ec2 server instance running with MySQL installed locally (not using RDS), and another backup server that runs MySQL replication as a slave to the live server.
I am now trying to generate daily automated SQL dumps, and so far I've been researching on AWS CLI to automate the whole process by

start an instance with AMI snapshot of live server (backup done daily)
run the mysql dump command
terminate the instance and delete the volume.

I got it working fully (the commands and so on), but I noticed an issue is that, the MySQL in the instance started via AMI is very slow, it takes 2-3x longer duration to generate a full backup (compared to doing it in live server).
I tried to not do it in the backup/slave server as we want the backup server's data to always be ready, but generating a mysqldump will temporarily require pausing of slave and resuming it later (meaning to say, there will be a lag for xx period of time, whereby xx is the time taken for mysql dump to be generated).
Is there any better solutions to this? We're not using RDS mainly due to the cost, hence we're doing it all manually.
